# Plotting a large number of stacked spheres generated from python-- mayavi? paraview and pyevtk? How to transmute .npy to .vtk?

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi

I want to produce plots like this, except with many more particles. Matplotlib is woefully inadequate.

[image: from google]

Right now I am using mayavi in python 3.5 running through a jupyter notebook. As I need to plot 5x10^5 spheres it will not be practical, since time is a limiting factor already at 2x10^4 spheres.

Here is my python code to produce the mayavi plot. I have a numpy array of values [a,r,x,y,z]. It's not relevant what the first quantity is for this problem.

```
"""VISUALIZATION WITH MAYAVI"""
#I think this is too slow to be practical. 
#view particles with mayavi
import mayavi
from mayavi import mlab
%gui qt

def plot_sphere(p):  #feed it p and get back a sphere \n",
    t1,R,a,b,c = p
    [phi,theta] = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:12j,0:np.pi:12j]  #increase the numbers before j for better resolution but more time
    x = R*np.cos(phi)*np.sin(theta) + a
    y = R*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta) + b
    z = R*np.cos(theta) + c
    return mlab.mesh(x, y, z)  

#run s over all particles and plot it
def view(particles): 
    for p in particles:
        plot_sphere(p)

view(spheres)
```

This code produces plots like this:

[image]

I have been told I should look into writing my numpy arrays to .vtk files using evtk, then visualizing these in paraview. I downloaded paraview and read [this](https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/09/06/numpy-to-vtk-converting-your-numpy-arrays-to-vtk-arrays-and-files/), but perhaps my version of python is limiting me? First, install pyevtk-- okay: 
I tried  conda install -c opengeostat pyevtk=1.0.0, but it fails due to incompatibility with my python version. I looked for details but could not find any.

Next I downloaded the repository [here][https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyEVTK/1.0.0], then used pip to install it successfully.

Next I put evtk.py, vtk.py, hl.py, and xml.py, and tried some examples in the repository-- none of them work. Seemingly there is some problem with

```
from .vtk import *
```

type commands. I tried replacing all of these in the four .py files with

```
from evtk import vtk 
from vtk import *
```

and such, but no luck. Long story short, I can't get pyevtk working to export my numpy arrays as .vtk files. I could use some help in this regard, or better yet I would love a different option to get my numpy arrays rendered by paraview. Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

[image: solved]

Ok, I solved my own problem. This image is made using paraview, after converting numpy arrays to a .vtu object using pyevtk.

Out of the box, the repository did not work, there was some problem with importing the modules inside the four .py files, so I modified them all. Instead of from .vtk import *, I changed it to from vtk import *, and so on, in every module in the library. evtk.py was not able to import a class from xml.py, so I just copied it and pasted, then deleted xml.py. After some tinkering and clueless modifying to make the errors go away, eventually it worked.